# How to facilitate dict record filtering by dict key value?

Tags: python, rocksdb

I want to interface with rocksdb in my python application and store arbitrary dicts in it. I gather that for that I can use something like pickle to for serialisation. But I need to be able to filter the records based on values of their keys. What's the proper approach here?

Comment: Arbitrary. Dictated might have different keys.

Answer (score 1):

so let's say you have a list of keys named `dict_keys` and you have a dict named `big_dict` and you want to filter out only the values from `dict_keys`. You can write a dict comprehension that iterates through the list grabbing the items from the dict if they exist like this:

```
new_dict = {key: big_dict.get(key) for key in dict_keys}
```

Comment: Does that mean that every record will be deserialized?

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB is a key-value store, and both key and value are binary strings.

1. If you want to filter by given keys, just use the `Get` interface to search the DB.
2. If you want to filter by given key patterns, you have to use the `Iterator` interface to iterating the whole DB, and filter the records with keys that match the pattern.
3. If you want to filter by values or value patterns, you still need to iterating the whole DB. For each key-value pair, deserialize the value, and check if it equals to the give value or matches the give pattern.

For case `1` and case `2`, you don't need to deserialize all values, but only values that equal to the give key or match the pattern. However, for case `3`, you have to deserialize all values.

Both case `2` and case `3` are inefficient, since they need to iterate the whole key space.

You can configure RocksDB's key to be ordered, and RocksDB have a good support for prefix indexing. So you can efficiently do range query and prefix query by key. Check the documentation for details.

In order to efficiently do value filter/search, you have to create a value index with RocksDB.